# Ломается разметка/верстка на Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Разметка экрана

```
@screen-xs-max: 769px;
@screen-sm-min: 770px;
@screen-sm-max: 1440px;
@screen-md-min: 1441px;
```

на промежутке от 980рх до 1440рх происходит вот такая штука: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а должно быть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При всех других версиях экрана все работает, и даже другие row работаю корректно(вот почему и не понятно почему именно тут ошибка). Не могу понять что сделал не так.
Вот ссылка на макет, там есть less файл. Если есть вопросы задавайте. Спасибо!
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6yBSacgA5HbeXdqSEhSQ0NObUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К странице в архиве подцеплены стили бутстрапа, которые отличаются от стандартных только отступами для строк и контейнеров. В них `col-md-3` срабатывает для `@media (min-width: 992px)`.

Нужно [пересобрать бутстрап](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=57e72c00e932fe42536d635eff5b26a4#media-queries-breakpoints) с вашими параметрами и подключать результат пересборки.

**UPD**. Пересобрал бутстрап, подставив `770px`, `1441px` и `2000px` в `@screen-sm`, `@screen-md` и `@screen-lg` соответственно. С новым `bootstrap.css` страница выглядит так, как нужно.

---

**Как работают классы колонок в бутстрапе**

В вашем коде только одна строка меняет своё поведение при переходе от `-sm-` к `-md-`. Это строка с классом `col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12`.

В бутстрапе класс для узкого экрана [продолжает действовать и на более широких](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries), пока его не перебьют новым условием. Например, `col-sm-12` действует на всех экранах шириной от 768 пикселей (`@media (min-width: 768px)`), а `col-xs-12`- вообще на всех.

Поэтому ваш код можно упростить:

- вместо `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12` достаточно `col-xs-12`;
- вместо `col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12` достаточно `col-xs-12 col-sm-4`;
- вместо `col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12` достаточно `col-xs-12 col-sm-8`и так далее.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться. А почему другие row нормально функционируют тогда. Я понял в чем проблема, не понял почему она возникла в одном месте

Comment: @АлександрАлексеев В вашем коде только эта строка меняет своё поведение при переходе от `sm` к `md`. Добавил к ответу объяснение.

Comment: теперь понял, еще раз спасибо!